# How to run a modeler stream from an SPSS Statistics syntax using SPSS's python interpreter

Tags: python, spss, spss-modeler

I have an IBM SPSS syntax file that I am trying to automate; I am looking for a way, inside SPSS Statistics, to open SPSS Modeler and run a stream. My SPSS syntax has to wait for the stream to finish and the output file to be created and exported from the Modeler stream before the SPSS syntax can continue. Is there a way to do this using native SPSS Syntax or using SPSS's python interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing a whole lot about SPSS, I suggest you try using a command line argument from python within SPSS. I don't have either at my disposal, but it might look a little something like this.

```
Start Program.
import subprocess
subprocess.call("modelerclient","-stream mystream.str -Pusername=\"Joe User\" -execute", shell=true)
End Program.
```

You may have to give an absolute path to the modelerclient, so it would be something like "C:\Program Files\IBM\Modeler\ModelerClient.exe", but that will depend on your system configuration. You can find the full path by right clicking the modeler shortcut on your desktop and viewing "properties". My reference links are below to get you started if the above doesn't work out of the gate.

[IBM Knowledge Center - Using Command Line Arguments](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3RA7_15.0.0/com.ibm.spss.modeler.help/batchmode_arguments_reference.htm)

[Python documentation on SubProcess library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)